# Perl: replace literal expression and literal variable names

Tags: perl, regexp-replace, ubuntu-22.04

When I use this expression:

```bash
echo '...${var}#other.([]);,=${var}#other${var}...' |
   perl -pe 's/\Q.([]);,=${var}\E/.([]);,=ok/'
```

As expected, the variable `${var}` is expanded to "" (empty value) and the output is obtained:

```
...${var}#other.([]);,=ok${var}#other${var}...
```

but I want:

```
...${var}#other.([]);,=ok#other${var}...
```

So I thought about escaping the variable:

```bash
echo '...${var}#other.([]);,=${var}#other${var}...' |
   perl -pe 's/\Q.([]);,=\${var}\E/.([]);,=ok/'
```

For some reason that I don't know, the supplied string doesn't match a portion of the input one and it doesn't get replaced:

```
...${var}#other.([]);,=${var}#other${var}...
```

Double `\\$` and triple `\\\$` backslashes don't match either.
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the `perlop` manpage (https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop):

> For the pattern of regex operators (`qr//`, `m//` and `s///`), the quoting from `\Q` is applied after interpolation is processed, but before escapes are processed. This allows the pattern to match literally (except for `$` and `@`). For example, the following matches:
>
> ```
> '\s\t' =~ /\Q\s\t/
> ```
>
> Because `$` or `@` trigger interpolation, you'll need to use something like `/\Quser\E\@\Qhost/` to match them literally.

So, in your case, you might write:

```
s/\Q.([])\E;,=\$\{var}/.([]);,=ok/
```

Comment: Why `}` is not escaped with `\}`?

Comment: @Mario Palumbo, Because Perl doesn't care about unmatched `}`. You could escape it, and I would, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a pattern as :

```
echo '...${var}#other.([]);,=${var}#other${var}...' |
   perl -pe '$pattern=q|.([]);,=${var}|; s/\Q$pattern\E/.([]);,=ok/'
# output : ...${var}#other.([]);,=ok#other${var}...
```

Answer (score 0):

`\Q` doesn't prevent interpolation.<sup>[1]</sup>

In fact, `\Q` is usually used as `...\Q$var\E...` to match the value of `$var` literally, and I find other uses taxing to read.

For readability, I would be tempted to use the following in this situation:

```bash
perl -pe'my $text = q{.([]);,=${var}}; s/\Q$text/.([]);,=ok/'
```

---

1. It also doesn't quote the delimiter (which is why `\E` is optional). And `\L` and similar work after `\Q`.